# Connect to a service in two or more ways, delegate method execution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, inheritance

I came across intriguing case, where I have to connect to a web service in two different ways, based on consumer preference. For the purpose of this question, I would prefer not to mention any products, let's say it is a web service called 'Service' and can be accessed by RestAPI and message broker.

My simplified code looks like this:

```
import configparser
import os

from MyApp.Exceptions import WrongModeException

class Service(object):
    cfg_file = 'path/to/cfg.ini'
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(cfg_file)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_password():
        return 'ToPsEcReTp4ssw0rD'

class ServiceAPI(Service):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = APIConnect(self.config.some_param)

    def do_stuff(self, a):
        self.connection.do_stuff(a=a)

class ServiceMessageBroker(Service):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MessageBrokerConnect(self.config.some_param)

    def do_stuff(self, a):
        self.connection.do_stuff(a=a)

class ServiceWrapper(Service):
    def __init__(self):
        mode = self.config.get(option='mode')

        if mode == 'Message Broker':
            self.service = ServiceMessageBroker()
        elif mode == 'API':
            self.service = ServiceAPI()
        else:
            raise WrongModeException
            os.sys.exit(1)

    def do_stuff(self, **kwargs):
        self.service.do_stuff(**kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ServiceWrapper()
    s.do_stuff(a='blabla')
```

Is there a better and cleaner way to do it? I was thinking about mapping appropriate functions in a dictionary and then use it to execute, but seems super ugly to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary as a function dispatcher, in my opinion, is clean and adaptable. I would prefer this to an `if` / `elif` / `else` construct, especially if it aids readability.

This, for example, seems more readable to me:

```
class ServiceWrapper(Service):
    def __init__(self):
        mode = self.config.get(option='mode')

        d = {'Message Broker': ServiceMessageBroker,
             'API': ServiceAPI}

        if mode not in d:
            raise WrongModeException
            os.sys.exit(1)

        self.service = d[mode]()

    def do_stuff(self, **kwargs):
        self.service.do_stuff(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I admit, looks cleaner. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you turn the wrapper into a factory?

```
def create_service():
    mode = ...
    service_classes = {'Message Broker': ServiceMessageBroker,
                       'API': ServiceAPI }
    try:
        service_cls = service_classes[mode]
    except KeyError:
        raise WrongModeException

    service_obj = service_cls()
    return service_obj
```

Comment: That's definitely an option. But I still would prefer it to be a class because of other reasons. Thanks!

Comment: Then you still need to forward each call explicitly, or do something more complicated like overriding the __call__ method - which is not something you should do lightly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly even more pythonic and clean solution that a friend of mine proposed, adapted to also include your suggestions:

```
import configparser
import os

from MyApp.Exceptions import WrongModeException

class AbstractService(object):
    cfg_file = 'path/to/cfg.ini'
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(cfg_file)

    def do_stuff(self, a):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ServiceAPI(AbstractService):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = APIConnect(self.config.some_param)

    def do_stuff(self, a):
        self.connection.do_stuff(a=a)

class ServiceMessageBroker(AbstractService):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MessageBrokerConnect(self.config.some_param)

    def do_stuff(self, a):
        self.connection.do_stuff(a=a)

class Service(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        mode = AbstractService.config.get(option='mode')

        class_mapping = {
            'Message Broker': ServiceMessageBroker,
            'API': ServiceAPI
        }

        try:
            chosen_class = cls.class_mapping[mode]
        except KeyError:
            raise WrongeModeException

        return super(Service, cls).__new__(chosen_class, *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ServiceWrapper()
    s.__init__()
    s.do_stuff(a='blabla')
```